# Homekit Implementation on Existing System

Tags: ios, iphone, ios8, mfi, homekit

I had a iOS app for home automation. my app works flow

**iOS app  <------> hardware device  <------>  accessory (home appliances)**

iOS app send and receive command via Sockets.

now i need to implement HomeKit to my existing System. how can implement without change of my hardware.

Should i  create a bridge(MFI compatible device) to communicate between iOS app to hardware device or any other ideas.

**iOS HomeKit  app  <------> Bridge(MFI compatible)  <------> hardware device  <------>  accessory (home appliances)**

if i must to create a bridge. how the bridge compatible with my hardware device.

Answer (score 1):

To make a bridge you have to sign up to the Apple MFI agreement. Once you've got the spec you can make your own hardware to talk between iOS (not just your app, Siri can send HomeKit commands to your bridge too) and your accessory. There would be little point in having it talk to the "hardware device" you listed above. Basically you'd be releasing a new hardware device that instead of receiving the custom protocol it does now, it will listen for HomeKit commands.

Comment: Hi craig thank for your response,i had a doubt, i had existing ios and android app, now both app communicate with my hardware device and send command to accessory . if i create a new hardware device (MFI compatible) with HAP protocol for ios then how can android app communicate with new hardware device (MFI compatible)?.If i created a bridge for ios can use the same bridge for android ? otherwise we use seperate hardwares for ios and android please advice.

Comment: Why can't a piece of hardware listen for both protocols?

Comment: Supporting Homekit as well as Android requires implementation of multiple protocols and provisioning methods (i.e. apple+proprietary or apple+standard). Don't expect it to be 'easy' or 'cheap', but it can be done!